# stuck getting nullpointer using inputstream

Tags: java

I'm stuck to get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
```

here is part of my code

```
InputStream isa = MainWindow.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/wis/lan/ui/Algo.txt");
    InputStreamReader isra = new InputStreamReader(isa);
    BufferedReader bra = new BufferedReader(isra);
```

can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `getResourceAsStream()` cannot find the file.

[ClassLoader#getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) is able to locate files relative to the "root" of the classpath.

It is recommended to use the ClassLoader as returned by `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` for this.

Comment: i just want to get algo.txt inside jar file at runtime, can you give me example  to do that

Comment: @user2458032 Running this code from IDE is not the same as running it from jar. Have you tried to run it from jar?

Comment: i resolve using
String resource = "algo.txt";
URL resai = MainWindow.this.getClass().getResource(resource);
fileGram = new File(AIdir.getAbsolutePath()+"/Algo.txt");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(resai, fileGram);